# what is object in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws

Trying to Provisioning Multiple ECS Services Using Terraform(for_each).
However getting the below error:

│ Error: Unsupported attribute │ │   on main.tf line 42, in module "ecs": │   42:   alb_target_groups = module.alb.alb_target_groups │    ├──────────────── │     │ module.alb is a object │ │ This object does not have an attribute named "alb_target_groups".

main.tf

```
module "alb" {
  source             = "./modules/alb"
  vpc_id             = module.network.vpc_id
  security_group_alb = module.security.security_group_alb
  public_subnets     = module.network.public_subnets
  customer_env       = local.customer_env
  env                = var.env
  alb_target_groups  = local.alb_target_groups
  listeners          = var.alb_config.listeners
}
module "ecs" {
  source           = "./modules/ecs"
  family_name      = var.family_name
  env              = var.env
  ecs_service_name = var.ecs_service_name
  service_config     = var.customer_config
  alb_target_groups  = module.alb.alb_target_groups
  # alb_target_groups      = local.alb_target_groups
```

env.tfvars

```
ecs_service_name = ["customer"]

alb_config = {
  name = "Public-Alb"
  listeners = {
    "HTTP" = {
      listener_port     = 80
      listener_protocol = "HTTP"

    }
  }
}
customer_config = {
  "customer" = {
    name          = "customer"
    is_public     = true
    container     = 80
    host_port     = 80
    cpu           = 256
    memory        = 512
    desired_count = 1
    alb_target_group = {
      port              = 80
      protocol          = "HTTP"
      path_pattern      = ["/*"]
      health_check_path = "/health"
      priority          = 1
    }
  }
}
```

cat modules/ecs/ecs.tf

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "main" {
  for_each                           = var.service_config
  name                               = "${each.value.name}-Service-${var.env}"
  cluster                            = aws_ecs_cluster.main.id
  load_balancer {
    #target_group_arn = var.target_group_arn
    target_group_arn = var.alb_target_groups[each.key].arn
    container_name   = var.container_name
    container_port   = var.alb_container_port
  }
```

locals.tf

```
locals {
  alb_target_groups = { for service, config in var.customer_config : service => config.alb_target_group }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is clear. Your `alb` module does not output `alb_target_groups`. This means you have to add the following output to the `alb` module:

```
output "alb_target_groups" {
   value = "values of the target groups you want to output" 
}
```

Alternative use

```
alb_target_groups  = local.alb_target_groups
```

instead of

```
alb_target_groups  = module.alb.alb_target_groups
```

if `alb_target_groups` are same.

Comment: If i use alb_target_groups  = local.alb_target_groups
getting the following error:

Comment: Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on modules/ecs/ecs.tf line 51, in resource "aws_ecs_service" "main":
│   51:     target_group_arn = var.alb_target_groups[each.key].arn
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.key is "customer"
│     │ var.alb_target_groups is object with 1 attribute "customer"
│
│ This object does not have an attribute named "arn".

Comment: @Vamsi This is a new issue. Your question does not even specify what `var.alb_target_groups` is. Please make new question with relevant details.